# How to fix Java JNI DLL dependencies

Tags: java, dll, dependencies, java-native-interface

I have a Java Application which has to load an DLL with a few dependencies. I copied all required DLLs in the same folder. The DLL I was set up uses the SeeingMachine FaceApi libraries. Now when I'm starting the Java application I will get an error the my DLL can't find the dependencies:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\[..]\bin_dbg\HeadTrackerDLL.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
            at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
            at Tracker.<clinit>(Tracker.java:12)
            at TrackerControls.<init>(TrackerControls.java:18)
            at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

How can I solve the problem? Because Dependency Walker does not show any error. And I don't wanna load ALL DLL files manually.

Comment: Please include the command line/script that's running java, confirm what your `library.path` is set to and that all the libraries are on that path.

Comment: Did you specify the java library path when you started your app?

Comment: I set this line into the eclipse VM arguments field:

-Djava.library.path=${workspace_loc}/bin_dbg/HeadTrackerDLL

also i tried 

-Djava.library.path=${workspace_loc}/bin_dbg

but nothing works.

Comment: `-Djava.library.path=${workspace_loc}/bin_dbg` looks correct.  Are all the libraries you need in that directory?

Comment: And before bin_dbg the project name. But does not work... Iif i did not call a function what depends on another DLL it works but if I some API function it does not work.

Comment: My DLL wants to call the IEFRAME.dll and the SHLWAPI.dll both are in the same folder like the HeadTrackerDLL.dll. 

http://img214.imageshack.us/img214/5573/dependencies.png

Because there are really much dependent DLLs how can i say to may application how and where to load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i think i fixed my problem with the mt.exe tool.

```
mt.exe -manifest HeadTrackerDLL.dll.intermediate.manifest -outputresource:HeadTrackerDLL.dll;
```

With this codeline the manifest file and the dll file will be packed into the dll file so all dependencies located.

My application runs. I hope this was the solution.